# Flink Disable Savepoint for specific state

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I manage 2 different states in one flink job. But i dont need to take savepoint for one of them. For other, i have to take savepoint.

I dont want to take savepoint for the one which is not necessary because it is going to increase savepoint duration and size.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I'm curious: what's the use case for using Flink state for something that doesn't need to be included in savepoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any state that Flink is managing will be included in all savepoints and checkpoints. Both types of state snapshots use the same underlying mechanism, and include all state.